# How to detect/listen for a class being added to an element on hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mutation-observers

I have a class added to my navigation on hover `.show-dropdown` and I would like to disable my scroll when the nav is initiated.

Is a mutation observer the best way to go about doing this or is it overkill?

I want to do something simple like

```
if($('.show-dropdown').length > 0) {
  window.disableOnScroll = 1;
}
```

unfortunately, this never gets called when the hover is initiated, I believe it is because it is only checking for the class on-load.

**Is a mutation observer my best bet?** Or should it be only used to listen for a `node/element` being added to the dom rather than a class?

Comment: What you mean by `nav` is initiated?

Comment: Any reason not to use `mouseover`?

Comment: @brk the nav has a dropdown that is revealed when hovered, that is what i'm referring to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable scroll when you enter an by subscribing to `mouseover` events.

In order to enable scrolling again, you will need to listen to `mouseleave` events as well. When those events are fired, re-enable scrolling.

An event delegator would be well suited for this so that you won't have to handle all the events in one place.

Comment: Thanks nipuna, i got it working with a mouseover/mouseleave combination :)
What do you mean by event delegator?

Comment: No problem. It's a method that's used to combine events from multiple elements(in your example, if you have multiple .show-dropdown). If you only have one you don't need them.